# using distinct with lambda expression with date

Tags: entity-framework

i wanna to get count of rows but when date is not repeat
as example

```
id name  date
1  ali   1/1/2014
2  hoda  1/1/2014
3  samir 2/1/2014
```

the right count is 2  because i want to count date one time 
i'm using entity frame work and lambda expression
i'm using below class

```
public class GroupAttend
{
   [Key]
   public int AttendID { get; set; }
   public int GroupID { get; set; }
   public int StudentID { get; set; }
   public int InstructorID { get; set; }
   public int TimeID { get; set; }
   public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
   public int LevelID { get; set; }
   public bool? AttendStatue { get; set; }
   public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
   public bool DelFlag { get; set; }
   public DateTime? DelDate { get; set; }
   public Guid UserAddID { get; set; }
   public Guid userEditID { get; set; }
   public Guid? UserDelID { get; set; }

}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int count = context.Table.Select(x => x.DateTimeProperty).Distinct().Count();
```

Comment: yes thanks , but does not work because i wanna to add condition
&&x.groupid==groupidParameter &&x.levelid==LevelIDParameter

Comment: And what stops you doing so?

Comment: yes i got is using
var count=uof.GroupAttends.List(g=>g.GroupID==groupID&&g.LevelID==LevelID).Select(d=>d.DateAdded).Distinct().Count();
            return count;
i will try now

Comment: You have no idea how LINQ works and how to use it, do you? You should read some tutorials. Otherwise you not only won't understand my answer but neither be able to write next one just by yourself.

Comment: no i know what i do , but mistake when trying , thanks your code is right